# вывод json jquery

Tags: jquery, json

Есть json с такими данными:

```
[
  {
    "title_ru":"Шерлок",
    "title_en":"Sherlock",
    "token":"33f9cd5b014686a122360f758b5f15ca14d",
    "type":"serial",
    "kinopoisk_id":502838,
    "world_art_id":null,
    "translator":"Дубляж",
    "translator_id":21,
    "iframe_url":"http://site.ru/serial/f9cd5b01686a122360f758b5f15ca14d/iframe",
    "seasons_count":4,
    "episodes_count":13,
    "category":null,
    "block": {
      "blocked_at":null,
      "block_ru":false,
      "block_ua":false
    },
    "last_episode_time":"2017-01-14 19:36:25"
  }
]
```

Беру их с внешнего источника: [Внешний источник](http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?kinopoisk_id=502838&api_token=e050c0cb3e5e1d7840fccfb35e3a35be)

Не пойму, как вытащить оттуда строку: `"seasons_count":4`

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Вы через ajax получаете её?

Comment: это точно JSON? Не js-массив?

Comment: @vp_arth спасибо за ответ! Данные берутся со стороннего источника: site.ru/videos.json - именно отсюда нужно взять информацию

Comment: По объективным причинам, мы не можем ничего взять из указанного источника. Если вы способны сами получить этот json - как его разобрать смотрите в моём ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Взять данные с внешнего источника можно с помощью [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Это API ещё в стадии экспериментального, поэтому рекомендуется пока использовать [полифилл](https://github.com/github/fetch) для кроссбраузерности.

```js
var url = 'http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?...';

fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  .then(list => list.forEach(function(item){
    var li = document.createElement('LI');
    li.innerHTML = item.title_ru + ' сезонов: '+item.seasons_count;
    document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
  }));
  

/// На ваш сервис нельзя делать кроссдоменные запросы, поэтому ниже я написал Mock функции fetch, вам он не нужен.
function fetch(url) {
  var json = '[{"title_ru":"Шерлок", "title_en":"Sherlock", "token":"33f9cd5b014686a122360f758b5f15ca14d", "type":"serial", "kinopoisk_id":502838, "world_art_id":null, "translator":"Дубляж", "translator_id":21, "iframe_url":"http://site.ru/serial/f9cd5b01686a122360f758b5f15ca14d/iframe", "seasons_count":4, "episodes_count":13, "category":null, "block": {"blocked_at":null, "block_ru":false, "block_ua":false }, "last_episode_time":"2017-01-14 19:36:25"} ]';
  return Promise.resolve({body: json, json: function(){
    return JSON.parse(this.body);
  }});
}
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

*С jquery вам нужно будет воспользоваться функцией `$.ajax`, но я не уверен, что знаю, как корректно его замокать)*

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0, $.parseJSON is deprecated. To parse JSON strings use the native JSON.parse method instead.

Comment: @splash58, убрал

Comment: @vp_arth можно переделать код, чтобы он парcил с внешнего источника: http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?kinopoisk_id=502838&api_token=e050c0cb3e5e1d7840fccfb35e3a35be

Comment: Можно, но в том или ином виде, это нужно добавить в вопрос

Comment: @vp_arth простите. отредактировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

С jQuery это выглядит примерно так

```js
var data = [{
  "title_ru": "Шерлок",
  "title_en": "Sherlock",
  "token": "f9cd5b01686a122360f758b5f15ca14d",
  "type": "serial",
  "kinopoisk_id": 502838,
  "world_art_id": null,
  "translator": "Дубляж",
  "translator_id": 21,
  "iframe_url": "http://video.filma4ok.ru/serial/f9cd5b01686a122360f758b5f15ca14d/iframe",
  "seasons_count": 4,
  "episodes_count": 13,
  "category": null,
  "block": {
    "blocked_at": null,
    "block_ru": false,
    "block_ua": false
  },
  "last_episode_time": "2017-01-14 19:36:25"
}, {
  "title_ru": "Шерлок",
  "title_en": "Sherlock",
  "token": "497f9659e0ee5e4a374bbb99ee412856",
  "type": "serial",
  "kinopoisk_id": 502838,
  "world_art_id": null,
  "translator": "Субтитры",
  "translator_id": 20,
  "iframe_url": "http://video.filma4ok.ru/serial/497f9659e0ee5e4a374bbb99ee412856/iframe",
  "seasons_count": 4,
  "episodes_count": 12,
  "category": null,
  "block": {
    "blocked_at": null,
    "block_ru": false,
    "block_ua": false
  },
  "last_episode_time": "2017-01-18 06:18:11"
}];


function parseResponse(data) {
  $.each(data, function() {
    var li = $('<li />');
    li.html(this.title_ru + ' сезонов: ' + this.seasons_count);
    $('#list').append(li);
  })
}

parseResponse(data);
/*
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://moonwalk.cc/api/videos.json?kinopoisk_id=502838&api_token=e050c0cb3e5e1d7840fccfb35e3a35be',
    method : 'get',
    dataType : 'json',
    success : parseResponse
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```